How to write a math formula in bibtex
I want to cite this paper in LaTeX but it gives me an error because of the math formula in the paper title. Any idea how to fix this?
@article{BuresDistance,
author  = {Bures, D},
title   = {An extension of Kakutani's theorem on infinite product measures 
           to the tensor product of semifinite {$w^*$}-algebras},
journal = {Transactions of the American Mathematical Society},
volume  = {135},
month   = Sep,
year    = {1969},
pages   = {199-212},
}


Sorry, I modified this! @DavidCarlisle

A claim such as "it gives me an error" is not actionable. Are you sure you understood the error (or maybe warning?) message correctly? Please edit your posting to state the exact wording of the error message.  Off-topic: Please also change author  = {Bures, D}, to either author  = {Bures, D.}, or (better still) author  = {Bures, Donald},. After all, the author's first name is not just the letter "D" all by itself. And please encase the name Kakutani in curly braces, to keep BibTeX from converting it to lowercase.

The file
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

abc \cite{BuresDistance} xyz

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{b.bib}
\end{document}

with b.bib
@article{BuresDistance,
author  = {Bures, D},
title   = {An extension of Kakutani's theorem on infinite product measures to the tensor product of semifinite {$w^*$}-algebras},
journal = {Transactions of the American Mathematical Society},
volume  = {135},
month   = Sep,
year    = {1969},
pages   = {199-212},
}

Produces

and no errors.
If you get an error you need to show an example and show the error message from the log, it must be due to code not shown.
I used the file unchanged from your post to show there is no error, although as Mico comments below you should use {Kakutani} to avoid the name being lowercased.
